# Slideshow of HTML files with iFrame

Tags: html, slideshow

I am trying make a slideshow to show several HTML files in one page (lets say in index.html).

If I have these files:

- region1.html
- region2.html
- region3.html

And I want those all showing like a slide show for each 5 minutes interval.
How do I do that?

Comment: Please share what you have tried  so far and then explain  exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for [asking proper questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You will need to use atleast javascript. If you like jquery then you may find some plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to cycle them through in sequence, you can add a line like the following to your page's `head` tags.

In *region1.html*:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;URL=region2.html" />
```